# TextRenderer.DrawString is not drawing a long string

Tags: c#, .net, textrenderer

The following code is not painting anything:

```
void Form3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
      string text = new string('m', 3000);
      TextRenderer.DrawText(
          e.Graphics,
          text,
          this.Font,
          new Point(10, 10),
          Color.Black,
          Color.Transparent);
}
```

Seems that the string is too long. If I change the string lenght to 2000 it works (I'm using SegoeUI 9) font.

Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: that's a lot of characters for one line. Draw text i have only seen it used to draw one line at a time using single or double space for multiple display. Anyhow try using `.DrawString()` instead.

Comment: What? You asked the same question 1 year ago and asking again? Seriously? Are you kidding? Probably can we expect same question next year?

Comment: Maybe this is a yearly ritual for him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your code block and it painted. So I increment the string length up to 4401. After that my test failed too.

Probably `TextRender.DrawText` method has a limitation on string. But I think that this limitation should be depended on machine.

You want to a workaround. So I suggest that `Graphics.DrawString` method.

```
string text = new string('m', 4401);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text,
                this.Font,
                Brushes.Black,
                new Point(0, 0)
                );
```

**Edited**

Oh! I searched this issue and I found this question on stackoverflow.

[TextRenderer doesn't draw a long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525640/textrenderer-doesnt-draw-a-long-string)

What a coincidence! You asked same issue before 1 year ago.